# Double to String Conversion of large numbers with exponential

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having a application in which I have to process very large numbers. Application API gives me number then I had to convert it into the string and send to further processing.
Code receives number as - 1535625179.1619387

Then for conversion I have used -

```
char buffer[255];
sprintf(buffer, "%e", OverallVolume); //OverallVolume has the above value.
```

Now here buffer variable return 1.535625e+009 which is normalized as 1535625000.00
BUT my application shows value as 1.5356252e+09 which is normalized as 1535625200.00

So I want to ask what method I should be using to covert Double to String so that my resultant value will match to the value shown by application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want 7 digits to appear after the decimal point. To do that specify a precision as follows:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%.7e", OverallVolume); // buffer contains 1.5356252e+09
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b236c893d74a41e7)

---

Also, since this is tagged C++, here's a version using IO streams that prints the same result.

```
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    double OverallVolume = 1535625179.1619387;
    std::ostringstream ss;

    ss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(7) << OverallVolume;
    std::cout << ss.str() << '\n'; // prints 1.5356252e+09
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43ac3e34b913eb95)